# Bubble Formation in Froth Flotation process

Tags: physical-chemistry, bubbles, chemical-compounds

I've recently attended a lecture on the metallurgical process of froth flotation. To make us understand froth, my teacher gave us the example of soap bubbles. But in actual practice, the flotation mechanism uses the process of mixing of pine oil and water, but they both sound to me like two different processes, could you please explain why froth is formed at all?

Comment: Shouldn't [chemistry.se] be a better place for this, as metallurgy is primarily dealt with in Chemistry.

Comment: @WrichikBasu - Some of us here know a bit about metallurgy since there is a connection with physics. For example, although my Ph.D is in physics my thesis advisor was a professor of Materials Science & Engineering. Probably a few others here who know some metallurgy, too. I have to admit, though, that I'm not familiar with the froth floatation process.

Comment: It's not that physicists will not know anything about metallurgy, because after one level, you cannot differentiate physics and Chemistry.  But this seemed a basic question, and hence I referred over to Chemistry SE.

Comment: -1. No research effort. Have you tried googling your title?

Answer (score 0):

The pine oil is acting as a frothing agent in the same way that soap does.

Pine oil contains a wide range of chemicals some of which are surface active just like the stearates in soap. It also contains compounds that will selectively bind to the ores and make them more hydrophobic, which enhances the separation. And finally it's cheap and easy to dispose of.

So don't be mislead by the fact it is an oil. In this application the pine oil is just a surfactant and therefore a frothing agent.